# How to Insert / Update a Row in MySQL / PHP At The Same Time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert into a MySQL row if the row doesn't exist, or update it if it does exist.

Something like this:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO table (Value1, Value2) VALUES ('$var1', '$var2') WHERE UniqueKey='$id'";
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (UniqueKey,Value1, Value2) VALUES ('$id','$var1', '$var2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value1 = '$var1',Value2 = '$var1';
```

Answer (score 3):

User MySQL's [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) command:

```
$sqlQuery = "REPLACE INTO table (id, Value1, Value2) VALUES ('$id', '$var1', '$var2')";
```

It works the same as a normal INSERT, but if the primary key (in you case 'id') matches then it will replace all the values specified.

Answer (score 0):

replace into table (UniqueKey,Value1,Value2) values ('$id','$var1','$var2');

replace is similar to insert, however if the unique key exists in table, it will delete first, and than insert.